# python meshgrid size and line thickness

Tags: python, grid, plot, matplotlib

I am trying to make a grid on the surface of my surfaceplot, now I know that wireframe does not work and the grid command is something else entirely. But I don't seem to be able to get grids like this [image] but rather grids like this[image] and changing rstride and cstride only makes it look like modern art:
[image]

Here is the plot command I am using

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection="3d")

plot = ax.plot_surface(x,y,z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, shade=True,
                       linewidth=1, antialiased=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you were clearer with what you are trying to achieve. The grid in your second plot looks fine to me - what were you expecting? How *exactly* do you want the grid to appear?

You say you are not happy with the result of changing the values of the `rstride` and `cstride` arguments, but you don't say what you are changing these to or from. Have you read the documentation on these arguments?

Also, please post a [minimal, self-contained working example of your code](http://sscce.org), since the grids drawn will depend on how you constructed your data (how many points in each dimension etc.). Don't make us go looking through your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12287946/623518)

Anyway, rant over. Simply doubling the `rstride` and `cstride` values gives me

[image]

not the thrid figure in the question. Is the above more like what you are after?